# Is there way to access a dialog by using context?

Tags: android, dialog, android-context

I'm doing an Android Instrumentation Test Case using the class ActivitiyInstrumentationTestCase2. I've displayed an dialog using the Activity context.

Activity.java

```
Dialog customDialog = new Dialog(this);
```

Is there any way to retrieve the dialog using the activity context in the test case activity?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code, you can use the method `getOwnerActivity()` to get the `Activity` that was passed to the constructor.

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Dialog.java/?v=source

It might be helpful to get the name using `getAssociatedActivity()` which returns a `ComponentName` (which is helpful if you have several layers of components that use the `Activity` context before creating the `Dialog`